# PHP: Get a file from path as a uploaded file

Tags: php, file, file-upload, path

I want to forward a file with a known path to a script that was intended for $_FILES["uploadfile"]. So how to get this code working:

```
<?PHP
$uplfile = "somefileinscriptdirectory.txt";
echo $uplfile["name"];
echo $uplfile["size"];
?>
```

Is there a way to get a file handle on the txt-File to work with like you would with a $_FILES[...]?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/stat. Otherwise, the only ways to get $_FILEs-type data is to actually do an upload, or build it yourself.

Comment: When I wanted to build the $_FILES manually, what shall I remember? Is there a documentation about the contents of $_FILES? I couldn't find one.

Comment: you didn't look very hard, then: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: What do you mean by *forward a file with a known path to a script that was intended for $_FILES*? Do you want to create a file in the air and get all status of that? Do you want to upload a created file in the air?

Comment: I want to modify the infinite filebase so that the upload is handled by a uploadifive. This jQuery code uploads the file into a temporary directory. I have created a hidden button on the upload page where the filename of the uploaded file gets stored. Then I want the Filebase to take the file from the temporary folder as it was an uploaded file. I got it with Marc B's post, there is only a "empty"-error thrown when I want to upload a file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fileinfo ( which is apparently native since php 5.3.0 )?
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.finfo-file.php